# Worklight core-web-layer.js errors

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

Can someone help me?
When I run my Worklight project on Chrome, Firefox or Opera I don't get any errors.
But when I run it on IE I get these errors:

```
    Error: multipleDefine 
    Error: multipleDefine 
    Error: multipleDefine 
    Error: multipleDefine 
    SCRIPT5002: Function expected 
    core-web-layer.js, line 311 character 160
    SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method '_eventHandler' 
    core-web-layer.js, line 165 character 71
```

When I run it on Android, the Dojo functionality also doesn't work and I get this error:

```
    07-09 13:12:37.817: D/CordovaLog(7180): Error: scriptError
    07-09 13:12:37.817: E/Web Console(7180): Error: scriptError at file:///data/data/com.Klappr/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:21
```

Comment: Which Explorer version are you testing on?

Comment: @IdanAdar I tested it on IE9.

Answer (score 4):

Is your `core-web-layer.js` the one that was created during project creation?

For your issue with running on Android, if you're using Worklight 6.0 with a new project, copy the following files from the Dojo Library project that was created alongside the Worklight project:

```
toolkit/dojo/dojo/nls/core-web-layer_ROOT.js
toolkit/dojo/dojo/nls/mobile-ui-layer_ROOT.js
```

These files then must be added to your Worklight project's `www/dojo/nls/` directory.

In addition to including the `*_ROOT.js` files, you may also need to remove the development configuration from the application. To do this, open the Console view (**Window** > **Show View** > **Other...** > **Console**). From the Console view, click the **Open Console** button and choose **Dojo Library Requests** from the list. From the Dojo Library Requests console, click the **View Menu** (the triangle in the toolbar), and uncheck **Provide Library Resources**. After this, build and deploy your application to your emulator or device.

Comment: Where in the documentation do they reference to the *ROOT.js files? It does solve the issue.

Comment: @DrissA, it's a defect... it's been fixed internally.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @IdanAdar! When is the update sheduled to be released? Besides that, how are updates for Worklight released, do you need to install a new Eclipse plugin or are there any update possibilities for a current installation?

Comment: If you're a customer, you can get the update - when available - from the customer portal. Otherwise it is a simple matter of checking for updates in Eclipse.

Comment: if this valid for WL 5.06?

Comment: @AngeloScafuro No, this is for Worklight Studio 6.0